# Ternary relationship hibernate saved in extra table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 entities that can have a relationship with each other. So a good step to solve this problem is to use another table to store the 3 ID's of the 3 entities. Lets say the entities are X, Y and Z.

```
@Entity
public class XYZ {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "X_ID")
    private X x;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Y_ID")
    private Y y ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Z_ID")
    private Z z;

    public XYZ(){

    }
```

}

Entities X, Y and Z have:

- Their own attributes and primary key
- @OneToMany to the X, Y and Z entities on the attribute private XYZ
  xyz; to make it bidirectional

Entity XYZ has have normal getters and setters for the entities X, Y and Z. I'm giving the whole entity.

Entities X, Y and Z are the parents and XYZ is the child. So deleting X, Y, or Z should delete XYZ.

From a relationship between two entities I know that you have to save the child on the parent side. Example:
 parent.addChild(c);
parent.save();

How can I save X, Y, Z in the new XYZ with the cascade working?
I don't want to save it 3 times (on the X, Y and Z). 
Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I haven't found good examples on this yet and my knowledge isn't enough.

I have this but dont know if it is right:

```
XYZ test = new XYZ();
test.setX(new X());
test.setY(new Y());
test.setZ(new Z());
test.save();
```

Now if i delete the X entity, is the XYZ entity that contains the X entity automatically deleted?

Comment: Do I understand it right, that each entity has a `ManyToMany` relationship with the other 2 entities? If yes, then you should implement it like this. There is no need for an additional entity which in turn causes more tables to be needed

Comment: Yes, that's why I made the XYZ table. But my question is how do I save for example X, Y and Z in the XYZ table. From my understanding you always have to save the child on the parent side. But here XYZ table has 3 parents.

Comment: Why do you refer to them as "parents"? Does `XYZ` extend all of them so they are actually the parents? From your code I would say no. You define who you "see" as parent. You can simple call `new XYZ().setX(new X()).save()` (that is just a rough example). You have to save a total of 4 times per created entry, because you have to save each of the 4 entities since you want it to be bidirectional

Comment: I call X, Y and Z the parents and XYZ the child because if X or Y or Z gets deleted the XYZ containing one of them also has to get deleted. 
You say I have to save it 4 times? But then I am going to have 4 records for 1 XYZ.

Comment: Shouldn't in the case that X gets deleted also Y and Z be deleted as well?

Comment: No the X, Y and Z are independent of each other. The relationship between them is saved in the XYZ. So naturally if X, Y or Z gets deleted the corresponding relationship gets deleted only in the XYZ

Comment: You stated earlier, that `I have 3 entities that can have a relationship with each other`. This means that the 3 entities are not independent of each other (at least it should be modelled like that). That means, that you should in class X add a field for Y and a field for Z. If you did the mapping properly, once you delete X, only the reference will be deleted but not the Y and Z objects. Since we don't know how your `X` class is modelled, we can't tell you if the `XYZ` object from the code will be deleted

Comment: Really sorry but could you put an example in an answer below? If 3 entities can have a relationship with each other I know there are multiple solutions. But here I just want to save them in a fourth table (XYZ) with its own ID. Class X, Y and Z don't have fields to each other because it all is saved in XYZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163850/discussion-between-xtremebaumer-and-urban).

Answer (score 0):

> I have this but dont know if it is right

I'm not sure what `test.save()` does, but if it calls `EntityManager.persist(test)`, then that's the correct way of doing it.

> Now if i delete the X entity, is the XYZ entity that contains the X entity automatically deleted?

Not by default. You will need `cascade = REMOVE` with the `@OneToMany` mappings, otherwise deleting `X` will fail. Note that this introduces a performance overhead compared to deleting the relevant `XYZ` in a bulk remove query. However, if the number of associations for a single `X/Y/Z` entity is small, you should be fine.

By the way, if the sole purpose of `XYZ` is to represent the ternary association, I'd consider:

- adding `optional=false` to `@ManyToOne`
- making the many-to-one associations into a composite primary key (this way will automatically prevent duplicates) and dropping the artificial id
- if you still want an artificial id, you should, at the very least, define a `@UniqueConstraint` involving all of the join columns (declaring the join columns as `updatable=false, nullable=false` is probably a good idea as well, just to be on the safe side)